# Can IIS be configured to serve different sites depending on the ip of the incoming connection?

Tags: security, iis-7

I'm looking to serve a "Work in progress" page to most of the internet, while allowing access to the site itself from a few specific, test, ip addresses.

Is this doable with IIS 7? How would you go about doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either utilize the IP and Domain Restrictions module, or download and install the URL Rewrite 2.0 module and use that. Here are 2 examples:

I would probably go with the following setup:

**Using [IP and Domain Restrictions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731598%28WS.10%29.aspx)**

2 websites:

> 1. www.website.com: No IP restrictions, "Work in progress" content
> 2. restricted.website.com: Appropriate IP restrictions, actual content

I would then have the root document (index.aspx, index.php, default.aspx, whatever), redirect users with the appropriate IP addresses, by using `Request.UserHostName()`(if .NET) or `$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]`(if PHP).

**Using [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite) Module**

A possible alternative, would be to use the URL Rewrite Module, to rewrite requests to the website, with the REMOTE_ADDR property as a condition.

```
<rule name="ip-rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="website.com" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="127.0.0.1" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="123.55.44.16" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="23.34.48.8" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="201.0.245.13" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.website.com/inprogress/default.aspx" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

This will automatically rewrite ALL requests NOT coming from the 4 predefined IP adresses, to /inprogress/default.aspx instead of the actual website